# OpenVPN port forwarding not working on VPS to Linux client

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, openvpn, iptables

Been through several Superuser and ServerFault questions and I am not able to get this working with `iptables`. I am trying to port forward a specific port `12345` through OpenVPN running on my Linux VPS (currently on Ubuntu 18.04) to the connected client (also Ubuntu 18.04). For all examples below the external IP of the VPS is `123.45.67.89` and internal IPs of `10.8.0.1` for VPS on the OpenVPN network and `10.8.0.2` for client. (Note this is a NAT VPS and I only have a few ports to work with in case that makes a difference, but I have full use of my assigned ports.)

I have tried the following on the VPS,

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 10.8.0.2 -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 10.8.0.2 -p tcp --dport 12345 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 12345 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```

as well as,

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2
```

but after all of these, online port checkers still report port `12345` as closed.

From the VPS I have also tried `telnet 10.8.0.2 12345` which outputs the following,

```
Trying 10.8.0.2...
Connected to 10.8.0.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

compared to `telnet 10.8.0.2 8945` (or any other port I'm not running a service on) outputs,

```
Trying 10.8.0.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Any help is appreciated. I have basically no experience with `iptables` so I am trying to get this working following various guides but none of them are opening the port.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by reinstalling Ubuntu on my VPS (lots of `iptables` rules that may have been misconfigured could have broken newer rules that would have worked). After reinstall the following `iptables` rule worked,

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:12345
```